# Windows crashes on doing sql dump

Tags: windows, import, crash, mysql

Windows simply crashes and opens the blue screen for dumping physical memory on trying to import sql dump.
So far I have tries 3 methods:

1. Through workbench

   Through command prompt using mysql command

   Through command prompt using mysql -h command

   Through ant ant import-database after creating data-sync folder

Windows crashes in all the 3 cases.

Versions:

> Your MySQL connection id is 5 Server version: 5.5.44-log MySQL
>   Community Server (GPL)

Workbench: 6.3.30
My system has 12 GB RAM.

Comment: What is the blue screen error code?

Comment: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL